# Create a view to a subdirectory of templates in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I'd like to create a TemplateView that displays all templates under a specific directory.

So for example I have

```
/staticpages/about-me.html
/staticpages/about-you.html
/staticpages/about-us.html
```

...

(many more)

In my urls.py i have
..

```
url(r'^(?P<page_name>[-\w]+)/$', StaticPageView.as_view()),
```

..

In my views.py i have

```
class StaticPageView(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return 'staticpages/%s' % self.kwargs['page_name']
```

However if someone goes to the url /staticpages/blahblah.html (which doesn't exist), It gets accepted by this view and a template not found error is generated. Howe can I redirect to a 404 if template not found?

Or alternately is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the project settings which will give you the templates directory. You can then use the os.listdir ( http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir ) to list all the templates present in that directory. Here is how one can achieve it. (The following code is not tested.. it is just to give you an idea)

The list of templates can be displayed like this:

```
# views.py
import os
from django.conf import settings

template_directory = os.path.join(settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS,'sub_directory')
templates = os.listdir(template_directory)
return render_to_response('template_list.html')
```

The corresponding template file..

```
# template_list.html
<ul>
{% for template in templates %}
  <li> <a href="/{{template}}"> {{template.filename}} </a> </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Hope that helps..